# Is gchart safe to use?

Tags: gwt, charts, gchart

The home page for [gchart](http://code.google.com/p/gchart/), a client side charting add-in for Google Web Toolkit (GWT), has a long screed about how the project's only maintainer thinks his Google account has been hacked and because of that he will be "disavowing/abandoning my own project and Google account".  Does that mean the project is an orphan?  Is somebody taking it over?

There is always a risk on basing your project on somebody else's code because they may stop supporting it or abandon it during your project's life time, but it seems to me that with the fast evolution of Java and GWT, using gchart in a new project may be a big mistake.  Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've released Client-side GChart 2.7 in a brand-new Google Code project (untainted by the previous rootkitting of my laptop) that you can find here:

http://clientsidegchart.googlecode.com

For details on the new security-related improvements I've instituted in an effort to prevent a future breach, follow the "release notes" link on the home page to the GChart 2.7 release notes.

I wish it had not taken me so long to re-release. I was attempting to correct the part of the problem that was under my direct control: my deep ignorance of all things related to computer security and systems administration.

I encourage you to give the re-released, better-secured and administered, Client-side GChart 2.7 a second look.

John C. Gunther, Client-side GChart author

Answer (score 1):

I would have to say so. If the only maintainer of the project has lost control of his account, using any subsequent versions of gchart could mean you're implementing malicious code un-knowingly.

Unless he spins up another project to move the code-base forward, I'd avoid it.